# swift 4.2 - how can I check with guard if a var has a valid enum value

Tags: enums, swift4.2

I need to check if a var, f.e. passed by a func, is a valid enum value. Not per se passed but just as an example here.

```
enum CollectionDict : String {  // Mapping to String Model = "Model" or should I ...
    case Model
    case Type
    case Element
    case ....
}

....
guard  InColectionDict != CollectionDict else { return false }
....
```

Obviously my sample guards line is wrong. What should I use or do to get the guard right or at least just compare/validate the InColectionDict variable with the enum CollectionDict in a one-liner?

I did hope to get away with..

```
func makeItem ( _ item: String , with key : String , inCollection : CollectionDict ) -> Bool {
    guard let res = CollectionDict.inCollection else { return false }
```

But it give me an error.
Of course thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Swift is strongly typed.  If your function has an non-optional Enum parameter, then at run-time it's guaranteed to be a valid enum value.

Comment: thank you, but let's pretend it is an optional. I thought I could get away with the added code part in my question above. but I get the error CollectionDict has noMember of inCollection

Comment: If it's an optional, you just need to make sure it's not null:  _guard let myEnum = myEnum else { return }_.  After that it's guaranteed to be valid enum value.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. Clear now, but what if I have a variable that can have different kinds of enums and their value? like enum1.xxx or enum2.yyy. I just want to know how I just can check if a variable belongs to a one enum or the other. I hope you get my drift that I would like to know how to compare. My sample wasn't thorough enough.

Comment: if you wanted to check if your enum is a specific value (for example if it's Model) use _guard let myEnum == CollectionDict.Model else { return }_

Comment: I know that, but at that point the enum value is in a variable. If I do it that way and I have 12 times 2 enum values, I got a very long switch. So what if Model is in a variable like InCollectionDict = "Model" or  InCollectionDict = CollectionDict .Model

Comment: Compare against rawValue.  Read this about using rawValue https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html